# Find maximum equidistant points on a line

Tags: python, algorithm

I need an algorithm to find maximum no of equidistant points on the same line.

**Input: List of collinear points**

For example: My points could be

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

In this case what I could do is sort the points based on their distance from origin and find the distance sequentially. However, in a scenario such as below the condition is failing. All the points are on the same line `y=-x+6`, and are equidistant from each other.

```
[(3, 3), (2, 4), (4, 2), (5, 1), (1, 5)]
```

because all the points are equidistant from origin, and sorting order could be anything so sequential traversal is not possible. 
For example, if final dictionary become this `[(3, 3), (5, 1), (4, 2), (2, 4), (1,5)]` we would end up calculating distance between (3,3) and (5,1), which is not correct. Ideally, I would want to calculate the distance between closest points so the order should be (1,5), (2,4).

To overcome this problem I created a O(n*n) solution by iterating using 2 loops, and finding frequency of minimum distance between any 2 points:

```
import sys
distance_list=[]
lop=[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)]
lop.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1])
for k in range(0, len(lop)):
    min_dist=sys.maxint
    for l in range(0, len(lop)):
        if k!=l:
            temp_dist = ( (lop[k][0] - lop[l][0])*(lop[k][0] - lop[l][0]) + (lop[k][1] - lop[l][1])*(lop[k][1] - lop[l][1]) )
            min_dist= min(min_dist, temp_dist)
    distance_list.append(min_dist)

print distance_list.count (max(distance_list,key=distance_list.count))
```

However, above solution failed for below test case:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)]
```

Expected answer should be: 5
However, I'm getting: 9

Essentially, I am not able to make sure, how do I do distinction between 2 cluster of points which contain equidistant points; In the above example that would be

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6)] AND [(10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)]
```

Comment: Could you provide some code to show what you try please?

Comment: What do you mean failing? if they are all equidistant from the origin any order is the right order for sorting...it's like sorting an array of the same number

Comment: And I need an algorithm to solve the travelling salesmen problem.

Comment: @DeepSpace Perhaps you could ask your own question, then.

Comment: @Nuageux added the code

Comment: @depperm sorting is of no use in this case. I wanted to do away with one iteration, but that was not possible because if the list becomes [(3, 3), (5, 1), (4, 2), (2, 4), (1,5)] distance between adjacent points no longer would be equal

Comment: "Expected answer should be: 5 Now, I'm getting 5"... and what is your problem?

Comment: @ChristianKönig Sorry formatting error, just updated it

Comment: Can people please explain why are they down-voting?

Comment: re down voting — I can't tell why down voting but  two people voted to close your Q because **unclear what you're asking** and another one because **off-topic**

Comment: @gboffi I accidentally hit save, and was formatting the question, in the meantime, people have down-voted I am guessing. Now, I believe it makes sense.

Comment: Are you supposed to assume all input points are collinear?

Comment: @user2357112 yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you want the distance of consecutive points, there is no need to calculate all combinations, you just need to calculate the distance of (p0,p1), (p1,p2), (p2,p3), and so on, and group those pairs in that order by the value of their distance, once you have done that, you just need the longest sequence among those, to do that the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) module come in handy

```
from itertools import groupby, tee, izip  

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def distance(a,b):
    ax,ay = a
    bx,by = b
    return (ax-bx)**2 + (ay-by)**2

def longest_seq(points):
    groups = [ list(g) for k,g in groupby(pairwise(points), lambda p:distance(*p)) ]
    max_s = max(groups,key=len)  # this is a list of pairs [(p0,p1), (p1,p2), (p2,p3),..., (pn-1,pn)]
    ans = [ p[0] for p in max_s ] 
    ans.append( max_s[-1][-1] ) # we need to include the last point manually 
    return ans
```

here the [goupby](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function group together consecutive pairs of points that have the same distance, pairwise is a [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes) to do the desire pairing, and the rest is self explanatory.

here is a test

```
>>> test = [(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)]
>>> longest_seq(test)
[(10, 12), (11, 13), (12, 14), (13, 15), (14, 16)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't solve the 2nd problem that I mentioned i.e the points could be on the same line, and distance is not the necessary criteria to find the consecutive points. For example, by using your code for the list:
test = [(3, 3), (2, 4), (4, 2), (5, 1), (1, 5)]
I'm getting : [(3, 3), (2, 4)] as the answer
and the correct answer would be whole list consisting all 5 elements

Comment: FYI: The input list does not necessarily in order

Comment: I got it list.sort() does the sorting for me thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the points in order, you don't need to sort them by distance from anything. You can just sort them by the default lexicographic order, which is consistent with the order along the line:

```
lop.sort()
```

Now you just need to figure out how to find the largest set of equidistant points. That could be tricky, especially if you're allowed to skip points.

Comment: Thank you! I never realized sort by default is doing this!